# Generalized Card Flipping Problem

Tags: probability

The problem goes as follow. Suppose that I have a total of $n$ cards, which $p$ are upwards, while $n-p$ are downwards. Let's say that I randomly choose $k$ of these cards to flip (upwards turn into downwards and downwards into upwards), so what is the probability that I am going to have $q$ of them upwards after this? The case for $k=1$ is fairly trivial, as we can only have $p+1$ or $p-1$ cards upward and it is fairly easy to see that the probabilities are going to be $(n-p)/n$ and $p/n$ respectively and all others are zero. For $k=n$ is also trivial, but for other values I am having some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $q-p$ should have the same parity as $k$. Let $k_1$ and $k_2$ be the numbers of flipped upward- and downward cards, respectively.

From the equations:
$$\begin{align}
k_1+k_2&=k\\
k_1-k_2&=p-q
\end{align}$$
we find $k_1=\frac{k+p-q}2$, $k_2=\frac{k+q-p}2$, so that the probability in question is:
$$
\mathbb P_k(p\to q)=\frac{\binom{p}{\frac{k+p-q}2}\binom{n-p}{\frac{k+q-p}2}}{\binom nk}.
$$